# How to load config xml for apache Ignite from resources

Tags: ignite

In my *java project*, I have `config.xml` in the

> java/main/resources

folder. How do I load it so apache ignite can pick it up?

```
Ignition.start("config.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the file in `java/main/resources/META-INF` folder. In this case it will be picked up automatically.